# Python egg: where is it installed?

Tags: python, macos

I'm trying to install py-appscript on the mac using 'sudo easy_install appscript'.
The command runs and I get a message saying "Installed /Library/Python/..../appscript=0.20.0-py2.5-maxosx-10.5-i386.egg".

However, when I run a tool that required this (osaglue) I get an error that py-appscript isn't installed. My guess is that it's installed in some location that's not in my path, or that I need to do something more to install it.

Any ideas?

The exact text I see when running easy_install is:

> Processing
>   appscript-0.20.0-py2.5-macosx-10.5-i386.egg
>   appscript 0.20.0 is already the active
>   version in easy-install.pth
>
> Installed
>   /Library/Python/2.5/site-packages/appscript-0.20.0-py2.5-macosx-10.5-i386.egg
>   Processing dependencies for
>   appscript==0.20.0 Finished processing
>   dependencies for appscript==0.20.0

and the error when trying to run osaglue is:

> Sorry, py-appscript 0.18.1 or later is
>   required to use osaglue. Please see
>   the following page for more
>   information:
>
> ```
> http://appscript.sourceforge.net/py-appscript/install.html
> ```
>
> Please install py-appscript and run
>   this command again.

Comment: can you import appscript from python?  Or, does that cause an error?
>>> import appscript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you have more than one version of Python installed on your machine? (Apple install their own copy of Python in /System, with third-party modules at /Library/Python, by default.) If so, chances are, easy_install is installing appscript for one Python, while osaglue is using another.

That said, if you're looking to generate glue code for objc-appscript, the simplest approach is to use ASDictionary (http://appscript.sourceforge.net/tools.html) to generate the glue directly; no need to mess around installing py-appscript and other dependencies.

Answer (score 4):

You can found all your avaiable packages in the sys.path. Start the pythonshell and type in this code:

```
import sys
print sys.path
```

Answer (score 0):

What does `which python` return?

Update: Ok, so go into /usr/bin and do a `ls -l | grep python`. Does `/usr/bin/python` link to the OSX installation?

If it does not, I had the same problem a while back. `easy_install` is installing the egg for the python package that came with OSX, but you're using a different version to execute code when you call python. I believe my solution was to reinstall setuptools and tell it to place the eggs in the location for the python distro that I wanted to use.

Comment: i think that's the problem

lrwxr-xr-x   1 root   wheel           72 Sep 19  2008 python -> ../../System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.5/bin/python

easy_install is installing to /Library/Python.

FUBAR. Cool, I'll try your workaround.

Comment: If you don't necessarily need the /System/Library/Framework distribution, you could just change the link to go to the /Library/Framework python.

Comment: Do not change /usr/bin/python to point to anything other than /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework.  In general, anything in /System and in /usr/bin are installed and managed by Apple.